# image should be moved to top during merging

Tags: iphone, ipad

hii guys,
 i am developing a project in which i placed two imagesViews on a view.each imageView on left and right of the view. each imageView contains two images like image1 and image2.I merged the both views and succeeded. image1 is under image2 after merging.

my requirement is image2 should be above image1.can anyone help me in this aspect

tnx in advance

```
- (void) _playIntro
{
    _playing = YES;
    //merge halfway between the two magnets
    CGRect mergeFrame = kFunny123MagnetBoundsIntroIpad;
    mergeFrame.origin.x = (self.imageMagnet.frame.origin.x + self.glyphMagnet.frame.origin.x)/2;
    mergeFrame.origin.y = (self.imageMagnet.frame.origin.y + self.glyphMagnet.frame.origin.y)/2;

    [_imageMagnet mergeWithMagnet:_glyphMagnet  atFinalFrame:mergeFrame withDuration:kMagnetMergeDuration];

    //[_glyphMagnet mergeWithMagnet:_imageMagnet atFinalFrame:mergeFrame withDuration:kMagnetMergeDuration];
    [self performSelector:@selector(_introFinished) withObject:nil afterDelay:kMagnetMergeDuration + kAfterMagnetMergedDuration];
}


- (void) mergeWithMagnet:(Funny123MagnetView *)otherMagnet atFinalFrame:(CGRect)frame
            withDuration:(float)duration
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"merge" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    BOOL showsTopImage;

    [self setFrame:[otherMagnet.superview convertRect:frame toView:self.superview]];
    [otherMagnet setFrame:frame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"mergeFinalize" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:duration];

    if (!showsTopImage)
    {
        [[otherMagnet _bottomImage] setAlpha:0];
        [[self _bottomImage] setAlpha:1];
        //[[otherMagnet _topImage] setAlpha:1];
        //[[self _topImage] setAlpha:0];
    }
    else {
        [[otherMagnet _topImage] setAlpha:1];
        [[self _topImage] setAlpha:0];

        //[[otherMagnet _bottomImage] setAlpha:0];
        //[[self _bottomImage] setAlpha:1];

    }


    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

_glyphImageView and _objectImageView are imageViews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the function sendSubViewToBack

[self.view sendSubViewToBack:self.imageMagnet];
and it worked

tnQ u all guys